# ViewModel contains list which is not bound when form is posted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

There is a property called `List<AssignablePolicy> AssignablePolicies` in my ViewModel. I want to create items that map to this list using Jquery. So I use this code:

```
$('#frmPolicy').append('<input type="hidden" name="AssignablePolicies[].CompanyName" value="' + company + '"/>');

$('#frmPolicy').append('<input type="hidden" name="AssignablePolicies[].PolicyNumber" value="' + policyNumber + '"/>');

$('#frmPolicy').append('<input type="hidden" name="AssignablePolicies[].Amount" value="' + amount + '"/>');
```

The AssignablePolicy contains CompanyName, PolicyNumber and Amount. However when I post the form I get null in AssignablePolicies in my viewmodel.

But when I do

```
Request.Form["AssignablePolicies[].CompanyName"]
```

the hidden form values are available. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Does the property on the model have a setter?

Comment: Yes this is the property:  public List<AssignablePolicy> AssignablePolicies { get; set; }

Comment: You might need to actually give it an index since it's a compound property, i.e. `AssignablePolicies[0].CompanyName`.  Note that the indices need to be consecutive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a compound property, you need to specify the actual index of each element.  When posted back these need to be consecutive (or you need to include an `.Index` element).  Here's some javascript adapted from a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194727/how-should-i-design-this-page/8194762#8194762) that will fix up the properties on post.  It assumes the first input in each set has the class `policy-start`.

```
$('form').submit( function() {
      $('.policy-start').each( function(idx) {
          var prefix = 'AssignablePolicies[' + idx + '].';
          $(this).attr('name',prefix + 'CompanyName')
                 .next(':hidden')
                 .attr('name',prefix + 'PolicyNumber' )
                 .next(':hidden')
                 .attr('name',prefix + 'Amount' );
      });
      return true;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem like this one.

Model class with a collection. The Request contains the keys but the collection was null. Long story short, I added a ICollection parameter in my controller to let the mvc bind the data.

See this walkaround, maybe it helps you: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx. It works for me. But, i'm a newbie.